# NextJS with Redux - store is empty after initializing

Tags: redux, next.js

Using following example:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper

After page has been refreshed getInitialProps get called and store get populated with initial state. But only on a server side. When comes to client side store is empty and initial state is passed a prop. Is there a way to set store state with initial state again or what should I do?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use redux persist with this example

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-persist